# Why doesn't my UV editing want to show?

Tags: uv

I decided I was going to cut a hole into my comb and when I when I finished, I went to check out UV edit to low poly my mesh and it only does the inside and not the outside.

[image]

Comment: Hello what do you mean by "it only does the inside and not the outside" ? In your screenshot, we can't see the UVs because your object is in Object mode, you need to switch to Edit

Comment: So the way I did the comb was I got a reference image and I traced it out with vertices. After tracing it out I clicked F fill it in and then extruded to make the mesh thick. When I go to UV edit the mesh that I traced out, now doesn't want to UV edit and when I add my low poly image it doesn't appear on my mesh.